# Can wxwidgets cpp be converted back to wsx?

Tags: c++, user-interface, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have some code where I lost the latest WxWidgets wsx files which are now out of sync with the GUI cpp files. This creates the issue where I cannot edit the updated version using Codeblocks/Wxsmith.
Is there a way to restore the wsx files from the cpp (which are up to date)?
Alternatively would there be a WYSIWYG way to edit the wxwidget GUI cpp files?

Comment: @man, ask on the CB forum. You have better chances.